Weighted KNN imputation
Consider the following piece of python code.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0],
                   [np.nan, 2]])
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors = 1, weights = 'distance')
imputer.fit_transform(df)

The output is
array([[1., 0.],
       [1., 2.]])

I don't understand why this output is correct: the distance between the two rows of the original table is strictly greater than 1, say d, and therefore the weight used for imputation is 1/d, and the value imputed should be 1/d which is strictly less than 1.

Isn't the imputation imputing the value of the n  nearest neighbors? Since there is only one, it's just using the single instance for computing the value.

@GuilhermeMarthe I used the parameter weights, which is supposed to "weight points by the inverse of their distance".

Sure, but there's still only one, so the weight doesn't matter.  "Weights" are normalized in kNN imputation so that they add up to $1$; it's a weighted average, in other words.  $\sum w_ix_i / \sum w_i$, for a highly-simplified example.  In inverse distance weighting, $w_i = 1/d(x_i, x^*)$.
